# Silk4Net & Silk Workbench integration

Tags: silktest

Is it possible to call scripts written in Silk4Net from Workbench? We are at the beginning of building an automation framework using SilkTest, and want to be able to express it to both our testers and developers.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately this isn't possible. You can call .NET Scripts from visual tests within the Workbench, but you can't call scripts between the various Silk Test clients currently.

**Update**: Reading your question again, it sounds like you just want some common code to share between scripts written in the Workbench, and scripts written in Silk4NET. If this is your goal, you could accomplish this by doing the following:

1. Create a new Class Library project in Visual Studio. It should target .NET 4.
2. Add a reference to SilkTest.Ntf to this project (this is the assembly that contains all of the automation classes used by Silk4NET and .NET scripts in the Workbench).
3. Put any common code into this assembly.

You can then reference this assembly from both your Silk4NET project and from .NET scripts in the Workbench.

Comment: Can we call a Silk4Net DLL from Workbench as described here? http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.silktest.workbench.doc/GUID-87B7BA19-19EA-4F97-BADC-0E7B07629732.html

Comment: @CaginUludamar I don't think that would work, since that feature is designed to call functions exported from standard Win32 DLLs, not .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Silk support today. Their reply is: "unfortunately there is no way to call the Silk4NET scripts in SilkTest Workbench. This is due to the fact that Silk4NETs scripts are built using the 4.5 .NET framework and Silk Test Workbenchs scripts are built using .NET 4.0. If you try to reference your assembly and call your methods and classes it results in compilation errors."